# determine total order question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> why it is not a total order.
>
> W on {a,b}* so that eVf iff length(e)<length(f)
>
> (empty,a) (empty,b) (empty,ab) (empty,ba)
>
> doesn't it a total order just like P(<=)case

Comment: It's not clear what '(empty,a) (empty,b) (empty,ab) (empty,ba)' means.

Comment: A total order on $\{a,b\}^*$ would have either $aVb$ or $bVa.$

Comment: i take P(<=)case as example
A={1,2,3,4}
{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,3),(3,4),(4,4)}
in W on {a,b}* so that eVf iff length(e)<length(f)
{empty,a,b}
(empty,a) (empty,b)(empty,ab)(empty,ba)
doesn't the similar pattern?

Comment: is that mean there is no (a,b)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V is a strict linear order iff for all distinct x,y, (xVy or yVx).
Since a /= b, (not aVb and not bVa) which is equivalent to
not (aVb or bVa).
Thus, since a and b cannot be compared, V is not linear (total).

Other incomparable elements are aa, ab, ba, bb.
In fact any two elements with the same length are incomparable by V.